# Solving A Simple Exponential floor Equation

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

So, there's this equation that I've been pondering upon:(to slove for n)
$\left\lfloor N\alpha ^{n} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor N\alpha ^{n+1}\right\rfloor+1$
I can't remove the floors for approximation purposes because that would distort the answer too much. But, I thought of using the definition of floors.That is if
$\left\lfloor k\right\rfloor = m$
Then:
$m\leq k < m+1$.
Thus, here we can say that we've
$\left\lfloor N \alpha ^{n+1}\right\rfloor+1 \leq N\alpha ^{n} < \left\lfloor N \alpha ^{n+1}\right\rfloor+2$
But that would only complicate the matters more.
Thus, I'm stuck down here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you are on the right track with thinking at the definitions. Write it as:

$$N \alpha^{n+1} \lt \lfloor N \alpha^n \rfloor \le N \alpha^n \lt \lfloor N \alpha^n \rfloor + 1 = \lfloor N \alpha^{n+1}  \rfloor + 2 \le N \alpha^{n+1} + 2$$

$$
\implies \quad N \alpha^{n+1} \lt N \alpha^n \lt N \alpha^{n+1} + 2
\quad \iff \quad \alpha \lt 1 \lt \alpha + \frac{2}{N \alpha^n}
$$

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Comment: I am not said downvoter, but  just to check, I think that should be a $2$ on the right hand side? Or a $\leq$

Comment: @BadamBaplan Thank you for the correction, edited and fixed.

Comment: Then finding  the value of $n$ using the inequality $ 1<\alpha+\frac{2}{N\alpha ^{n}}$ ? @dxiv

Comment: @Mooncrater Right, and $\,\alpha^n \lt \frac{2}{N(1-\alpha)}\,$ will give a lower bound for $n\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I think you're talking about an upper bound.

Comment: @Mooncrater No, that inequality actually gives a lower bound since $\alpha \lt 1$ and once the inequality is satisfied for $n_0$ it will automatically be satisfied for $\forall n \ge n_0\,$. But I realize that my hint doesn't address the upper bound. Is there any additional known relation between $N$ and $\alpha$ in that context?

Comment: @dxiv No. We've to find one. :)

Comment: Well since we have $\alpha < 1$, if we take $N,\alpha > 0$, then we have a simple upperbound for $n$.  $N\alpha^n < 1$ implies $N\alpha^{n+1}$, which is no good because in that case they both floor to zero, and so the left side of your equation is one whereas the right side is $0$.  Since $N \alpha^n$ is monotonically increasing, that gives an upper bound on $n$ as $\alpha^n < \frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan $N\alpha^n$ is monotonically ***de***creasing but, yes, $N \alpha^n  \ge 1$ gives an upper bound for $n$. Whether it's the *best* upper bound, however, is not obvious, which is why I was asking about additional known relations between $N$ and $\alpha\,$ in a previous comment.

Comment: Oh yes, **de**creasing i meant.  And yes unfortunately I think it's a pretty bad upperbound.  
There can be tons of discontinuous (in a discrete sense) solutions to this problem.  Consider $N = 5, \alpha = .9$, which has solutions $n = 15, 8, 4 , 2, 0, -2, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -11$. [See wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer+solutions+floor(5*.9%5En)+%3D+floor(5*.9%5E(n%2B1))+%2B+1)